# can we create sharing rule on contentdocumentlink object for share an files/image to guest user in experience cloud?

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, security, experience-cloud

I am storing images in files and I want to get that images without authentication for guest users. So I want to create sharing rule on contentdocumentlink object and share records with guest users. So is there any solution to get file records without authentication?